# How can I just only change my notification remoteInput color?

Tags: android, notifications

When I use "Notification.setColor(int argb)", my notification name and remoteInput have both change color, like this picture. but I just want change remoteInput color, How can I do this?[wrong example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8GU3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a different color for the remote input area - it always uses the same color you've set via `setColor()`

Comment: This is a pity, can‘t I make my notification more colorful(not use self-defined remoteView stye)? Anyway，thank you

Comment: Yeah, I guess they were assuming the color is strongly tied to your app and that the consistency would help users understand who is receiving the text they are tying (your app).